# Ошибка компиляции скрипта svn_bz_append.pl

Tags: perl

Пытаюсь настроить связку SVN - Bugzilla. При компиляции скрипта возникает ошибка (см внизу):

Для библиотек (DateTime, DBI и пр), которые используются в Bugzilla и которые внутри него, создал линки из каталога /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1, который присутствует в переменной [[[@INC](/users/2686/increazon)](/users/2686/increazon)](/users/2686/increazon).

Помогите решить проблему.

> `Can't locate loadable object for module DBI in @INC (@INC contains:
> /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
> /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
> /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
> /usr/lib/perl/5.10
> /usr/share/perl/5.10
> /usr/local/lib/site_perl . contrib .)
> at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/DBI.pm line 268 
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/DBI.pm line 268. 
> Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 33.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 33. 
> Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 44. 
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 44. 
> Compilation failed in require at /var/svn/svn_bz/svn_bz_append.pl line 40. 
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/svn/svn_bz/svn_bz_append.pl line 40.`

Answer (score 1):

Так установите libdbi-perl, например, если debian-based система. Зачем через линки-то делать?

Comment: Дык чайник, c linux никогда дело не имел. А стоит точно debian.

Comment: поставил.
теперь вот такая фигня:
DBI object version 1.612 does not match $DBI::VERSION 1.616 at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/DynaLoader.pm line 215.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/DBI.pm line 268.....

Теперь надо линки рубить?

Comment: Да, уберите, что раньше сделали (линки).

Comment: Убрал все линки пришел к исходному состоянию:
Can't locate DateTime/Helpers.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl . contrib .) at /usr/lib/perl5/DateTime.pm line 12.

С этим я боролся линками, а как надо?

Comment: Все получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Очень рад за тебя, что все получилось.
hashcode исправляет все "ты" на "вы", да еще орфографию и пунктуацию правит... Шок.

Answer (score 0):

Покажите код, как вы делаете инклуд модулей, ошибка именно в том, что в [@INC](/users/2686/increazon) нету нужного location.

Comment: Ну собственно это мне было и понятно, поэтому я и сделал линки.
весь код модуля можно посмотреть в
http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/svn_bz/trunk/

use strict;
use warnings;
#use Text::Wrap;

my $SVNLOOK = "/usr/bin/svnlook";
# chdir "/home/sysop/bug/bugzilla"; - это путь к bugzilla
BEGIN {
        chdir "/home/sysop/bug/bugzilla";
        push @INC, "contrib";
        push @INC, ".";
}
use Bugzilla;
use Bugzilla::Config;
use Bugzilla::Bug;